# Formula Field or Process Builder Firing which happens first

Tags: process-builder, formula-field

I have a scenario when my record is created initially there is a formula field which is a checkbox(false). In the middle of logic i change my record values and so the formula field would become true. on other side I have Process Builder which uses the formula field while performing an action. To my surprise the Process Builder is considering the false output instead of the new one. Is this how it should be behaving. Help me with any work around.
There is something missing out in the order of execution.

Comment: Formula fields does not participate in the order of execution. It's calculated on fly when you try to query or access them. One thing you can do is to insert a code to recalculate formula fields using `recalculateFormulas();` method.

Comment: @RohitMourya That's not "quite" correct. Formulas are loaded/calculated during certain phases of the transaction process, it's just not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: In the scenario I have mentioned when the record is updated and the process builder fires the formula field will be holding the existing value as the process builder fires before the database commit of the updated record and the formula field gets calculated after the database commit. I hope that was the gap missing. So the work around I could think of is Process Builders and any other business logic should be taking up the values directly from the fields instead of depending on the formula fields. Thanks for the hint guys. I resolved the issue.